# How can i format csv for this script?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a script which scans all servers in AD and returns local group members. Can you help me to update script so that output format will be grouped by server with heading – Server name, Local Group Name, Members, Type?

```
# Define local groups to audit
$groups = "Administrators", "Remote Desktop Users";

# Add Active Directory powershell plug-in
import-module activedirectory;

# Get all servers from AD and ignore predefined list 
$adservers = get-adcomputer -filter {operatingsystem -like "*server*"} | where {$_.enabled -eq $true} | sort name;

# Loop through each server found in AD
foreach ($adserver in $adservers) {


# Set server name from AD object
$servername = $adserver.name;

# Check if server is pingable
if((test-connection -computername $servername -count 1 -quiet)) {

    # Loop through each group to audit
    foreach ($group in $groups) {

        # Define the localgroup in the correct format
        $localgroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$servername/$group";

        # Get members of the local group
        $members = @($localgroup.Invoke("Members"));

        # Loop through each member found
        foreach ($member in $members) {

            # Define name and type of the member
            $memberName = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null);
            $memberType = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null);

            # Build CSV string
            $outstring = $servername + "," + $group + "," +$membername + "," +$membertype;
            # Output string to screen
            write-host $outstring;

            # Append CSV string to file
            $outstring >> c:\temp\localgroupaudit.csv;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of:

```
        # Build CSV string
        $outstring = $servername + "," + $group + "," +$membername + "," +$membertype;
        # Output string to screen
        write-host $outstring;
```

Unless writing to the screen is something you want, change to:

```
[Array]$results = $results + [PSCustomObject]@{Servername=$servername; LocalGroupName=$group,Members=$membername,Type=$membertype}
```

And after the end of all your loops:

```
$results | Export-CSV C:\path\youwanto\exportfileto\filenamehere.csv -notypeinformation
```